# Git log to show commits either by author OR commit message

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to use git log (open to other suggestions) to list all commits that either

- Were done by a specific author

or

- Which have a specific word in their commit message

I know how to search for each separately, but I would like a single list containing all matching commits. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `git rev-list` to generate both sets of revisions (which you combine and sort according to whatever criteria you like), then use `git log --no-walk --stdin` to read the combined list and show each commit.

Comment: @torek And to combine both sets, I need to use something external to git? I was mainly looking for a built-in way to achieve this, but if it doesn't exist I guess I can script something out.

Comment: Yes. If you just concatenate the two lists, that might suffice - I have not tested this to see how Git behaves (`git log` may do its own sort or may show them in stdin order).

Comment: @torek Cool! I tested and it works! If you add your answer, I will approve it, and add my final solution as a question edit. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git rev-list` to generate the hash IDs that `git log` should show, and then use `git log --no-walk --stdin` to read those IDs, sort them according to the usual `git log` sorting criteria, and show them.  (Note: This will occasionally change the output order from what you would see with `git log` *without* `--no-walk`.)

For instance:

```
(git rev-list --author 'A. U. Thor' HEAD;
 git rev-list --grep 'pattern' HEAD) |
git log --no-walk --stdin
```

(split into three lines for posting purposes; some command line interpreters will require that the command be a single line when actually used).