# git command- get all the files from latest last 8 merged commits excluding a commit with message "Commit only Delta Changes [ci skip]"

Tags: git, shell

i want to get all the files associated with the latest last 8 merged commits but excluding a commit 
either with a

1. commit message "Commit only Delta Changes [ci skip]" 
                           OR
2. Username "SF Admin"

I'll store all of these files in an array variable then.

What would be the git command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement something very similar to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234392/4526019

and then for each commit run `git show --pretty="" --name-only <commit id>`